# как очистить график в QCustomPlot?

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qcustomplot

отображаю график из 80 позиций , но когда вывожу на печать ресуется все 100 позиций.
Пытался использовать `wGraphic->graph(0)->clearData();` ничего не дало, а также `wGraphic->clearPlottables();  wGraphic->clearGraphs();`это вообще приводило к ошибке памяти.

.h

```
...
    QCustomPlot *wGraphic;      // Объявляем объект QCustomPlot
   ...
    QVector <double> x; // пока так размеры выставим
    QVector <double> y;
```

.срр

```
    // Инициализируем объект полотна для графика ...
    wGraphic = new QCustomPlot();
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(wGraphic,2,0,5,5); // ... и устанавливаем
...
 // Добавляем график на полотно
    wGraphic->addGraph(wGraphic->xAxis, wGraphic->yAxis);

    // Подписываем оси координат
    wGraphic->xAxis->setLabel("итерации");
    wGraphic->yAxis->setLabel("Дб");

    // Устанавливаем максимальные и минимальные значения координат
    wGraphic->xAxis->setRange(0,100);
    wGraphic->yAxis->setRange(-50,50);

    // Отрисовываем содержимое полотна
    wGraphic->replot();

    // добавляем красную линию на график
    wGraphic->addGraph(); // red line
    wGraphic->graph(0)->setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 110, 40)));
...
    // тут размеры отрис векторов
    x.reserve(80);
    y.reserve(80);
    // устанавливаем одно значение для всех элементов
    x.fill(0);
    y.fill(0);
...
    x << str_x.toDouble();
    y << str_y.toDouble();

//    qDebug() << "str_priem: " << str_priem;


    qDebug() << "str_x: " << str_x;
    qDebug() << "str_y: " << str_y;

//    wGraphic->graph(0)->clearData();


    wGraphic->graph(0)->setData(y,x);     // Устанавливаем координаты точек графика

//        wGraphic->clearPlottables(); выдаёт ошибку памяти
//    wGraphic->clearGraphs(); выдаёт ошибку памяти

    // Отрисовываем содержимое полотна
    wGraphic->replot();

    //  ???
    wGraphic->update();

    // Очищаем принятую строку
    str_priem.clear();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*а хотелось чтобы было что то типо такого*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Заменил  файлы `qcustomplot.cpp`, `qcustomplot.h` на те которые скачал по ссылке  https://github.com/eugesh/QCustomPlot  работает также как и преведущий вариант

из плюсов теперь при вызове `clear`  не разваливается программа .

```
void MainWindow::slotProcessDatagrams()
{
    QByteArray baDatagram_in;
    do {
        baDatagram_in.resize(m_pudp_in->pendingDatagramSize());
        m_pudp_in->readDatagram(baDatagram_in.data(), baDatagram_in.size());
    } while(m_pudp_in->hasPendingDatagrams());

    QDataStream in(&baDatagram_in, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_3);

    in >>  str_priem; // принимаем сообщение

    str_x = str_priem.section(' ',0,0);
    str_y = str_priem.section(' ',1);

    x << str_x.toDouble();
    y << str_y.toDouble();

    qDebug() << "str_x: " << str_x;
    qDebug() << "str_y: " << str_y;

    // чистим старое отрисовываем новое
    wGraphic->graph(0)->clear();
    wGraphic->graph(0)->rescaleAxes();

    wGraphic->graph(0)->setData(y,x);     // Устанавливаем координаты точек графика

    // Отрисовываем содержимое полотна
    wGraphic->replot();

    // Очищаем принятую строку
    str_priem.clear();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: За Ваш вопрос можно поставить стрелку вверх, потому что действительно непонятно, почему в qcustomplot не работает из коробки очищение графиков, но оформлен он не совсем понятно, все в кучу смешано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем ошибка была одна я почему то думал что выставив размер вектора , он сам будет всё выправлять , но это оказалось не так

```
void MainWindow::slotProcessDatagrams()
{
    QByteArray baDatagram_in;
    do {
        baDatagram_in.resize(m_pudp_in->pendingDatagramSize());
        m_pudp_in->readDatagram(baDatagram_in.data(), baDatagram_in.size());
    } while(m_pudp_in->hasPendingDatagrams());

    QDataStream in(&baDatagram_in, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_3);

    in >>  str_priem; // принимаем сообщение

    str_x = str_priem.section(' ',0,0);
    str_y = str_priem.section(' ',1);

    if(my_int >= 80)
    {
        // clear firs element
//        x.pop_back();
//        y.pop_back();
//        x.removeLast();
//        y.removeLast();
        x.pop_front(); //последний из вектора 
        y.pop_front();

        x << str_x.toDouble();
        y << str_y.toDouble();
    }
    else
    {
        x << str_x.toDouble();
        y << str_y.toDouble();
        my_int = my_int + 1;
    }

    // чистим старое отрисовываем новое
    wGraphic->graph(0)->clear();
    wGraphic->graph(0)->rescaleAxes();

//    wGraphic->replot();     // Отрисовываем содержимое полотна
    wGraphic->graph(0)->setData(y,x);     // Устанавливаем координаты точек графика

    wGraphic->replot();     // Отрисовываем содержимое полотна

    // Очищаем принятую строку
    str_priem.clear();
}
```

Правда новая ошибка прыгнула (почему то последняя и первая точка почему то соединяется , не знаю как разорвать)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каков вопрос, таков ответ)) Самое главное, что Вы разобрались!

Comment: @eugesh вы полностью были правы , в коде ошибок не было , а также вектору я задавал размер, кто бы знал что это фикция  и надо руками удалять элементы вектора .

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то для очищения графика я реализовал функцию:

```
template <class DataType>
void QCPAbstractPlottable1D<DataType>::clear()
{
    if (!mDataContainer.isNull())
        if (!mDataContainer->isEmpty())
            mDataContainer->clear();
}
```

Которую вызываю:

```
            graph->clear();
            graph->rescaleAxes();
```

Comment: попробовал увы     `wGraphic->graph(0)->clearData();`
    `wGraphic->graph(0)->rescaleAxes();`  ничего не поменялось , а  `wGraphic->graph(0)->clear();` и `wGraphic->clear();` пишет ошибку "такой функции нету." . Спасибо за ответ .

Comment: Помог мой способ? У меня вроде бы так работает. Если что не так - я еще посмотрю.

graph(0)->clear(); - реализация в первом сниппете. Добавьте ее в qcustomplot.cpp - и в .h файле void clear(); внутри класс QCPAbstractPlottable1D в public секции.

Comment: здравствуйте можете пожалуйста пример скинуть простейший минимальный , я его скачаю и посмотрю что я делаю не так , а то у меня чёт не выходит .

Comment: Я все храню на гитхабе - https://github.com/eugesh/QCustomPlot, файлы qcustomplot.cpp, qcustomplot.h

Comment: https://github.com/timob256/signal_emulator1 добавил вас в проект , там минус название , единицу надо убрать . Просто решил показать , даже интересно стало что именно я делаю не так (это конечно если время будет  и так сильно помогли )

Comment: Я собрал, запустил, но где мне брать данные, Вы же их как-то передаете через QUdpSocket?

Comment: Я просто не смог воспроизвести проблему, т.к. не построил графики.  
С виду все правильно, только я реализацию `clear` в cpp файл вписал, но это не должно быть принципиально.

Comment: данные она сама передает по локальному . Я отключаю  интернет и ставлю оправить порт 5000 принять порт 5000 . И в общем принимаю, там просто формула 10  косинус + 5 градусов (до 360) каждое отправление

Comment: У Вас все работает. Добавьте  `wGraphic->replot();` перед `m_graph->setData(y,x);` и посмотрите под отладчиком. Вы просто в `setData` передаете полностью весь график и отрисовываете по новой.
Ну и на всякий случай еще замечу, что метод `QCPGraph *QCustomPlot::graph(int index) const` константный, и поэтому вызов `wGraphic->graph(0)->clear();` - некорректный.
Лучше сохранять указатель на график отдельно
`m_graph = wGraphic->addGraph(wGraphic->xAxis, wGraphic->yAxis);`  и потом вызывать `m_graph->clear();`

Comment: Интернет кстати зачем отключаете?

Comment: для удобства :-)